# multiple instances of mods in eclipse for minecraft

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I've heard of using multiple mods in eclipse when making minecraft mods, but when I try to do that with 2 mod packages minecraft crashes. I'm going back and fourth between an tutorial mod, and my personal, and i would like to work on both at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out Pahimar's Let's Mod series on youtube. He covers a lot of subjects including the scenario you are trying to implement. I use a setup similar to what he describes in Episode 6:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU3MmJGnqSc

All of Pahimar's Let's Mod videos:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQPiZYWovwmnlE5eM3enBKhTNCg8-JDU1